# got to detect browser stand-alone event using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, node.js, browser

I want to detect browser stand alone event using jquery. here is the complete problem details :

I have developed nodejs chat application, in this we getting connection lost event after some time, i would like to do reconnect with nodejs.

So can you let me how to detect stand alone event, if i got this event then will reconnect.

Hope you understand my problem.

Thanks  in Advance.

Comment: No we don't understand your problem. Please edit the question and include code examples of what you have and a specific example of what you consider "connection lost event". HTTP is a stateless protocol so there's no such thing as lost connection.